# Where can I find reviews of lenses?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, reviews

I want to check reviews when deciding to buy a lens. There are so many factors beyond what is written in the name. Where can I find such reviews? What information does each site cover? Which reviews are most comprehensive? Which sites do the most meticulous scientific measurement, and conversely, which sites cover important subjective factors which are hard to put a number to?

Note that in general, comparing between mounts is not a good idea. (Even comparing lenses on a different shared mount than your own is a bit better.)

This is a "community wiki" post, where answers do not have individual ownership. Please use the answers to rate and comment on each site.

Comment: Good initative! Question about mainaining the list; should edit your original post or simply post each new site suggestion in a separate answer? Not sure which one would be best. If we post one site per answer people can use the voting mechanism to indicate "quality" of the site (it doesn't affect rep points since it's community wiki anyway).

Comment: I'd say one site/post, because it does still take some rep to edit community wiki posts, and for the voting as you described.

Comment: I envisioned one wiki post, but voting and individual comments on each site is pretty valuable as well and I like that idea.

Comment: @Eruditass: I actually think they can be combined. We could have the original post link to the individual answers. That way there is an "index" that is easy to navigate, and there is also a "rating mechanism".

Comment: You could make each lens site a comment so that we could upvote the site/comment. This is a very useful resource. Thanks Eruditass

Comment: @labnut, I think that's a great idea.  If anyone has any comments on a link, add it as an answer with some comments (or see if there is already one and add a comment)

Answer (score 30):

[The Digital Picture](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/) has good reviews of lenses for Canon bodies - pretty much every lens I've looked for has been there. They also do reviews of some lenses for Nikon bodies, of Canon bodies and of some accessories. When I've been looking for Canon lens reviews that's where I seem to end up.

Comment: +1 for The Digital Picture. It should be noted that he has started doing Nikon reviews now as well, so it is no longer just for Canon (although there is definitely more canon stuff there.)

Comment: @jrista: Can you point me to one Nikon review on his site (that doesn't say that content provided is part of a bulk upload)? Because I surely can't find any. But he's surely marvellous at Canon gear. +1

Answer (score 10):

My favorite is dpreview, which has a [Lens Review Widget](http://www.dpreview.com/lensreviews/widget/Fullscreen.ashx) that is pretty cool. They don't have a whole lot of lenses available in the widget, but you really get a good feel for the quality of the ones they have added.

Comment: I like the ability to easily compare lenses in their Lens Review Widget. I wish they would review new lenses as they come out, like they do with DLSRs.

Answer (score 10):

[DxOMark](http://www.dxomark.com/index.php/en/Lens-with-Camera) give a quantitative rating on how well a lens works on a given camera model based on the data they collect for the lens correction tool in their DxO Optics Pro application.

It's another data point to use in addition to a hands-on review.

Answer (score 9):

[Ken Rockwell](http://www.kenrockwell.com/) does reviews as well, though I will avoid waiting for the comment from Reid and point out that some folks think he is insane... :-)

Comment: Ha! Didn't realize I had acquired such a reputation. :)

Comment: It's worth noting that he sometimes reviews gear based on the specifications alone without ever actually using it...

Comment: I have read 3 of his so called reviews now and actually found myself laughing out loud while reading them.

Comment: not insane, just insanely self centered :)

Comment: On Ken Rockwell and reliability: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/are-equipment-reviews-from-websites-like-kenrockwell-com-and-bythom-com-reliable

Answer (score 6):

It isn't a lens review site per se, but [lenshero.com](http://www.lenshero.com) is a great tool for comparing lens options.

Like Snapsort for cameras, they've got a [lens comparison tool](http://www.lenshero.com). The front page features a [walk-through find-me-a-lens thing](http://lenshero.com/), which I find slick but not so useful if you've got some idea to start with. More usefully, the [search/sort](http://lenshero.com/lenses/digital-camera-lens) page lets you drill down based on specific needs, for example [Pentax K Prime Lenses for less than $500](http://lenshero.com/lenses/prime-lens-for-pentax-k-less-than-500).

Answer (score 4):

[Thom Hogan](http://www.bythom.com/nikon.htm) specializes in reviewing Nikon gear. I always check his site when I am checking out some new gear.

Comment: +1. Thom's reviews are superb. He talks a lot about what a lens is really like and how it can (or can't) be useful to you in real use, rather than spewing tons of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

[Pixel-Peeper](http://pixel-peeper.com) is a great site if you want to look at pictures that other people have created with the lens.  It shows all the EXIF information with the picture, as well as the size in megapixels.  Unfortunately, some flickr pictures have been removed.  The best part, however, is you can get a history of the lens's prices from ebay, which is filterable by location and convertible in currency.

Answer (score 2):

[Photodo](http://www.photodo.com/) has a collection of lens reviews.

Answer (score 2):

[Nikonians](http://www.nikonians.org/resources/reviews/nikon-lenses) has got a collection of reviews on various Nikon lenses.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a review site, but http://www.photosynthesis.co.nz/nikon/specs.html may be of interest to Nikon users, since it lists the specs (from max and min aperture to physical size and weight) for every Nikon lens; linked pages even include information like the serial number ranges for each lens model.

Answer (score 2):

[Lens Tip](http://www.lenstip.com) is a lens review site that is more detailed than Photozone. They haven't reviewed as many lenses, but I've found the reviews to be very detailed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [fredmiranda](http://www.fredmiranda.com/reviews/) has the most comprehensive user generated reviews for canon nikon mounts

Comment: Canon and Nikon-mounts only, as far as I can see....

Comment: But they have different brands like sigma for canon  http://www.fredmiranda.com/reviews/index.php?cat=46 (Sigma for canon)

Comment: Yep. It is a good and useful site.

Answer (score 2):

[Bjorn Rorslett](http://www.naturfotograf.com/index2.html) has been reviewing lenses for Nikon for many years and has a great website.  He employs a scientific approach to lens analysis, even rating their use for IR and UV photography.

Answer (score 2):

Let's not forget the reviews on [lensrentals.com](http://www.lensrentals.com). While it's not a dedicated review site, it may as well be. There's lots of great information in there from people who've been using the lenses for years.

Comment: Where are the reviews?  I picked a few lenses at random and looked around for reviews, didn't see any, unless you mean the overview given by lensrental staff?

Comment: It's probably fairer to call them "micro reviews", but here are a few: https://www.lensrentals.com/rent/canon/lenses/normal-range/canon-24-70mm-f2.8l-ii https://www.lensrentals.com/rent/canon/lenses/normal-range/canon-24-70mm-f2.8l-ii https://www.lensrentals.com/rent/canon/lenses/macro/canon-100mm-f2.8l-is-macro

Comment: And unlike almost any other lens review sites, they often test dozens of samples... Very cool.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who cares about Minolta/Sony equipment, there are a few sites worth noting:

1. [Dyxum.com](http://www.dyxum.com) is has a large lens database and many member-written reviews. Like most enthusiast reviews, ratings tend toward the high side.
2. [Kurt Munger](http://kurtmunger.com/) has a chart of Minolta/Sony equipment and quite a few equipment (especially lens) reviews. Lens testing is based on real-world subjects, not charts.
3. [Michael Hohner](http://www.mhohner.de/) has a few equipment reviews, and a large equipment database with links to other reviews.

Answer (score 1):

[LensTip.com](http://www.lenstip.com/lenses_reviews.html) has got good reviews, more you can find on [Optyczne.pl](http://www.optyczne.pl/obiektywy.html) but this site is in polish.

Answer (score 0):

DxOMark have already been recommended so I am going to add lens reviews on DPreview at 
[DPreview Lens Review/Preview](http://www.dpreview.com/lensreviews/).

Comment: Also already listed, actually.