# What are some good online tools for finding compatible lenses?

Tags: lens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A website that can help me in choice of new lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10859/a-website-that-can-help-me-in-choice-of-new-lens)
>   [Where can I find reviews of lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/where-can-i-find-reviews-of-lenses)

What online tools are available to find compatible lenses for a given camera?