# Which 70-300mm f4-5.6 lens is "better?"

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon, zoom, telephoto

I'm looking for a budget telephoto lens and I'm wondering which of these two is the better option. They have very similar specs:

[Tamron AF 70-300mm f/4.0-5.6 Di LD Macro Zoom Lens for Canon Digital SLR Cameras](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EXOXVA)

[Sigma 70-300mm f/4-5.6 DG Macro Telephoto Zoom Lens for Canon SLR Cameras](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000AM7CJ0)

This is for my Canon EOS XTi. Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/lens-review-sites

Comment: I would splurge and get the Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4.0-5.6 IS, but that doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: For what it's worth I have the Tamron and am very happy with it. It's not world-class but for the price they're going for at the moment you can't go far wrong.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: Thanks. I did end up ordering the Tamron because the reviews seemed slightly better.

Comment: Yeah. When I got it I checked the reviews, which assumed the full price. They said it was good value; I got it for nearly half price so I figured it was worth a shot. And it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked fred miranda for reviews and ratings?

http://www.fredmiranda.com/reviews/

He does a great job breaking down the lenses.