# Confused about different optical zoom on different lens

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, focal-length, optics

I'm looking at 3 different lens mainly for distance shots but with  a bit of Macro occasionally.

Tamron AF 70-300mm F/4-5.6
Nikon AF-S DX NIKKOR 55-300mm f/4.5-5.6G
Sigma 70-300mm f4-5.6

The bit I'm confused about is the optical zoom.  I thought if they all had the same Max Focal Length that they'd have the same optical zoom.  However what the spec's say is that the Tamron is 2x, the Nikon 5.5x and the Sigma 4.28.

Can someone explain why the optical zoom is so different?

Thanks

Edit:
Spec's got from here:
[Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tamron-AF-70-300mm-4-5-6-Macro/dp/B0012UUP02/ref=pd_vtph_421_lp_t_3?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=DAS62WVEH6P2J8WN7CGV) comparison about half way down the page

Comment: "Zoom" is not the maximal focal length, it's the difference between the minimum and maximum focal length expressed as a ratio - so 300/70 = 4.29x for the Tamron and Sigma, and 300/55 = 5.45x for the Nikkor.

Comment: @twalberg why did you post your answer as a comment?

Comment: Related: [How do I choose a lens for my first DSLR to replicate the capabilities of my bridge camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/91710/15871)

Comment: Related: [Lens quality impact on sharpness](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87986/15871)

Comment: Related: [How is the quality of the Sigma 18-300 DC Macro lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/48536/15871)

Comment: Related: [Why are large zoom ratio constant apertures lenses not generally available?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56424/15871)

Comment: [What are the tradeoffs when replacing two zoom lenses with a superzoom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/23155/15871)

Comment: [Why prefer the 18-55mm and 55-250mm lenses vs 18-200mm?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38741/15871)

Comment: [Which Lens Should I Use For A Single Lens Solution On Sony a6500?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/92816/15871)

Comment: [What superzoom lens should I buy for the Nikon D5100?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43122/15871)

Comment: [Can I convert binocular zoom to equivalent lens focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87917/15871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three zoom out to 300mm i.e. that is the maximum magnification. The 70 – 300 has a zoom range, the minimum vs. maximum is 300 ÷ 70 = 4.28. The 55 – 300 has a zoom range of 300 ÷ 55 = 5.5. The 70 – 300 has a zoom range of 300 ÷ 70 = 4.28. The difference is the span of the zoom from minimum to maximum. All three have the same maximum zoom but the minimum magnification is different. Two have a minimum focal length of 70mmm, one has a minimum focal length of 55mm.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between "zoom" and "focal length". Not sure where you got your data from though, because that Tamron and Sigma have the same zooming capability (4.28x zoom).

Comment: I think it was the odd Tamron  spec that must have confused me.  Thanks